# run jquery validationEngine plugin depending which submit was clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form like so.

```
<form name="theform" id="theform">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" id="one"> 
<input type="submit" id="two">
</form>
```

I am trying to use this validation
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

What I need to happen is if id#two is clicked the validation occurs, if #one is clicked it just submits the form.

I have it working for both buttons right now. I am not sure how to set it up using this plugin to do what I need it to do because this plugin binds itself to the submit buttons.

```
$("#theform").validationEngine({
    ajaxFormValidation: false,
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
            $('#ccformmain').submit();
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using the [gold standard of jQuery form validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugins?  It does not "bind itself" to the submission button.  In fact, a submission button is not even required for [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind to a 'click' event on the second button and detach the validationEngine

```
$('#two').on("click", function () {
  $("#theform").validationEngine('detach');
});
```